# A random walk with an exit

Tags: probability, random-walk

Let's consider a random walk.

We start on the tile $n_0$.

For our $q$th step, if we're already on the tile $k$ then we have a probability $P_{q,k,p}$ to go to the tile $p$ with  $p\in\mathbb{N}$.

The first action (moving from tile $n_0$ to another tile/staying on tile $n_0$) is the step number $1$.

The tile $0$ is the exit: if we reach it, the walk ends.

**Let $n,m\in\Bbb{N}$, what is the probability to have stepped on the tile $n$ exactly $m$ times when our walk has ended ?**

---

**Edit: let's consider a simpler case than the one above**

For any step, we have a probability $P_{k,p}$ to move from tile $k$ to tile $p$ where $p\in\{k-1,k,k+1\}$ (we can move by one tile at most)

Comment: Surely you realize that for general $P_{q,k,p}$s, the answer will be an awful mess... Is there any more specific case you would have in mind?

Comment: @Did I simplified the problem, does it seem reasonable now ?